# how can I update a table in one schema to match a table in a second schema

Tags: sql, oracle, schema

How can I update a table in one schema to match a table in a second schema assuming the only difference is additional fields  and indexes in the second. I do not want to change any of the data in the table. Hoping to do it without laboriously identifying the missing fields.

Comment: Let me clarify. Here,by "update" you mean  synchronize tables' structure?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no `ALTER TABLE THIS_ONE MAKE IT LOOK LIKE THAT_ONE` command. You'll have to identify the differences and write the appropriate DDL to add columns, indexes, constraints, etc. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

A elegant solution to this can be a DDL trigger that is triggered on a ALTER, CREATE ddl_event that applies the same changes to the first table (in one schema) as in the second table(that is another schema) in the same transaction.

Link --> https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS2008

Answer (score 1):

A little known but interesting recent addition to the Oracle DBMS artillery is  DBMS_COMPARISON.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_comparison.htm

Haven't tried it myself, but according the document should be able to get you the information at least without having to do any heavy scripting.

I've been doing this sort of thing since Oracle7 and always had to resort to complex scripting.